# How to trigger unobtrusive javascript when the content is dynamic with ajax (Lightbox)

Tags: ajax, jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

I've got some links coming in from ajax that need lightbox functionality:

```
<a href="..." class="lightbox"><img src='...'></a>
```

Normally this is given behavior via an on page load handler, but since the content is coming from ajax, the UJS isn't getting triggered.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the content is coming from AJAX, then din't setup the event handling during page load. Instead, let the event bubble to the topmost container that is not being changed or replaced by AJAX. Worst case, use `document` as the topmost node.

```
$('<root element selector>').on('click', 'a.lightbox', function() {
    // activate lightbox on the clicked element.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're triggering the ajax requests, but if it's with jQuery which seems likely, you can bind the lightbox in the success callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/route',
    success: function (response, status) {
        $('.lightbox').lightbox();
    }
});
```

You can pass in a context to the jQuery selector so you don't re-attached the lightbox to links that are already in the page, for example if your ajax call is adding the links to a div with id 'lightbox_links', use this selector instead:

```
$('.lightbox', '#lightbox_links').lightbox();
```